# Laravel 5.8: How to add a custom anonymous route to the Laravel's core file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel 5.8 application and I need to add a custom anonymous route to the Laravel's core file which is [Router.php](https://pastecode.io/s/pj3dht9y) and located in this directory:

**/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing**

I checked the file but since it does not have any `map` method, so I couldn't define the route.

So the question is how can I add the route in this case?

Comment: I know this is not a good way to add route, but I WANT TO DO IT ANYWAY!

Comment: Could you explain your reasons?

Comment: This file do not define any routes, instead is the router itself, and have methods to be used to define routes. So, again, what are you tring to archieve?

Comment: @EliasSoares For backdoor purposes

Comment: @EliasSoares I need to define a route which should not be seen inside web.php or any other route files.

Comment: @EliasSoares How can I define a route directly inside laravel core files?

Comment: Well... the big problem is if you define a route there, it will be wiped out as soon as someone runs  `composer update` and laravel's version changes (even if it's something very minor, like going from 10.0.0 to 10.0.1).

Comment: Another possibility is hardcoding an extra route in the compiled routes file created by `php artisan route:cache`, (`/bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php`) I don't think anyone is going to check there but again, it's going to get wiped out as soon as someone runs the command again.

Comment: Another possibility is that you create a custom laravel package with a Service Provider that registers the secret route, then require it as a dependency for the project and pray nobody notices it.  This will completely hide the route from the project since laravel auto discovers packages.

Comment: Still, you only need to run `php artisan r:l` to get a list of all routes. If someone is looking for it it *will* be found.

Comment: And finally, since your objective really is just a glorified backdoor and this is a laravel 5.8 project, the most reliable way to get one is to simply find a security that has been fixed *after* laravel 5 stopped receiving security fixes and exploit it. Some packages like the guzzle client also tend to have security issues. You can probably find some just running `composer audit`.

Comment: How about extending that class and register it in the container instead of the parent under the same name? Once extended you can add to it your route.

Another ideea would be using macro if possible.

Comment: You can add aditional route files in `RouteServiceProvider`

Answer (score 2):

**Sweet small answer: [vendor-patches](https://github.com/symplify/vendor-patches)**

**Detailed answer (Recommend reading)**

I don't have much knowledge about Laravel so I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing it rather than updating vendor files.

But I do understand that sometimes it's required to absolutely update the vendor/package files.
For Node, we use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to apply and manage our custom patches that are applied to the packages all the time and are tracked in git so they can be applied on all env and be available for all the developers.

Similarly, for Composer packages, there is [vendor-patches](https://github.com/symplify/vendor-patches).

I found an article for [patching vendor packages](https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2020/07/02/how-to-patch-package-in-vendor-yet-allow-its-updates/) that shows how to create and manage the patches but be mindful of this and only use this when it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: This seems like the only viable option to me! Good job!

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a line like:

```
$this->get('/hiddenroute', function(Request $request) { return 'hello, I am an hidden route';}); // $request is optional
```

as last line in the *__construct()* method of */vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php* ?

Comment: One will not edit vendor files.

Comment: @MikeDoe that was the request, i gave a possible solution ;-)

Comment: This is not a solution. One must not edit vendor files.

Comment: @MikeDoe I take note of your opinion, thank you